# Can I force emulator to think that simState is TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am making an app that reacts to TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED.

can i simulate this state on an emulator, though adb or through some other measure ?